# SimpleXML load file error for cli PHP script

Tags: php, cli

I am using the following code in the Joomla Cli to import news items into articles on a client's website. It was working perfectly until yesterday when an error was reported and no news items were imported.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

define('_JEXEC', 1);

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php')) {
  require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
  define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
  require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

$app = JFactory::getApplication( 'site' );

class BulkArticles extends JApplicationCli {
  public function doExecute(): void {
    $this->out(JText::_('Start'));

    // Fetch the JSON data and Run the insertArticle bulk data import to articles function
    $curlOpts = [
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.dtn.com/publishing/news/articles?categoryId=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C16%2C17&limit=10&maxAge=15&apikey=redacted',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ];
    try {
      $fetchedArticles = $this->curlToObject($curlOpts);
      if ($fetchedArticles) {
        $this->out(JText::_('Fetched Articles: ' . count($fetchedArticles)));
      }
      $insertedIds = $this->insertArticles($fetchedArticles);
      if ($insertedIds) {
        $this->out(JText::_('Inserted IDs: ' . implode(', ', $insertedIds)));
      }
    } catch (exception $e) {
      $this->out(JText::_($e->getMessage()));
    }
    $this->out(JText::_('Complete'));
  }

  /**
   * @throws Exception
   */
  private function curlToObject(array $curlOpts): array {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch); // Get the last error
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($error) {
      throw new Exception($error);
    }
    return json_decode($result);
  }

  /**
   * @throws Exception
   */
  private function insertArticles(array $articles): array {
    require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/article.php';
    $articleModel = new ContentModelArticle([]);

    foreach ($this->removeDuplicateAliases($articles) as $article) {
      $articleData = [
        'id' => 0,
        'catid' => 13,
        'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
        'alias' => JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title),
        'introtext' => strip_tags($article->storySummary, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
        'fulltext' => strip_tags($article->content, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
        'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
        'state' => 1,
        'access' => 1,
        'created_by' => 386,
        'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
        'language' => '*',
        'metadata' => [
          'xreference' => $article->dtnpfUrl,
        ],
        'attribs' => [
          'show_publish_date' => 1,
        ],
        'rules' => [
          'core.edit.delete' => [],
          'core.edit.edit' => [],
          'core.edit.state' => []
        ],
      ];

      if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
        throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
      } else {
        $newIds[] = $articleModel->getItem()->id;
      }
    }
    return $newIds ?? [];
  }

  private function removeDuplicateAliases(array $articles): array {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
      ->select('a.alias')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('a.catid') . " = " . $db->quote('13'));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $aliasLookup = array_flip($db->loadColumn());

    foreach ($articles as $i => $article) {
      if (isset($aliasLookup[JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title)])) {
        unset($articles[$i]);
      }
    }
    return $articles;
  }
}
JApplicationCli::getInstance('BulkArticles')->execute();
```

I ran the following command `php -d display_errors dtn-news.php` in the cli directory and the following error was returned: `Error: Call to undefined function Joomla\CMS\Language\simplexml_load_file(): Call to undefined function Joomla\CMS\Language\simplexml_load_file()`.

SimpleXML and the associated PHP extension are both installed.

The server PHP error logs are not reporting anything out of the ordinary.

Any ideas on why this just stopped working? Could it be something with the API? I have redacted the key for privacy and security reasons.

Cheers,